# Why is the sum of bytes integer?

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, byte, type-mismatch

I have tyo byte variable

```
byte a = 3;
byte b = 4;
```

If I sum them, the value of sum is integer.

```
byte z = a+b  //error, left side is byte, right side is integer
```

Why a+b is int?

Comment: There is no `+` operator for `byte`.  `byte` is promoted to `int` before being processed by `+`.

Comment: I expect the sum of bytes will be byte.

Comment: @user2693979 your expectations and the language specification differ ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) says so

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion
>   (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted
>   type of its operands.

and, [regarding numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2),

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So the `byte` values are promoted to `int` values and added up. The result of the expression is the promoted type, therefore an `int`.

You can simply cast the result

```
byte z = (byte) (b + a);
```

but careful with overflow/underflow.