# Calculate abs(byte1 - byte2) with result in byte without casting to int

Tags: java, byte, absolute, difference

I have two byte variables byte1, byte2. I know that the difference byte1 - byte2 will involve an implicit casting to int. But if I am interested in the *absolute* value of the difference, and want to get abs(byte1-byte2) again in byte format, is there a way to avoid casting back to byte, i.e. avoid

```
byte diff = (byte) abs(byte1-byte2);
```

Background is efficiency in performing a large number of such differences.

Comment: No it's not possible without cast. see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895078/why-is-the-sum-of-bytes-integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895078/why-is-the-sum-of-bytes-integer)

Comment: On modern processors, arithmetic calculations are performed on whole 32- or 64-bit words, so you won't gain any performance improvement avoiding casting even if it were possible

Comment: what comes into mind, is to join 4 byte pairs into 2 integers or 8 pairs into 2 longs and perform arithmetic on such composite words; but I'm not sure that composition and extraction will be faster than processing each byte pair separately

Comment: @JohnnyWiller very likely OP needs absolute difference between bytes treated as unsigned, e. g. to produce difference map between 2 images etc.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes, I understood. I told him to read that question because explain numeric promotions, that is happening is his situation

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suspected. (just thought, there may be some byte shift trick...)