# Inconsistency in treatment of Addition Assignment operator in Java

Tags: java

I am seeing inconsistent behavior when using a simple assignment operation.

```
class TestInt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte a = 1, b = 1;
        b = b + a;
    }
}
```

causes 
TestInt.java:4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
                b = b + a;
                      ^
1 error

whereas this compiles and works fine

```
class TestInt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte a = 1, b = 1;
        b += a;
    }
}
```

I do understand why the first piece of code may fail, I just cant figure out why there is a difference between the 2, coming from the C programming world.

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895078/why-is-the-sum-of-bytes-integer

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/javas-compound-assignment-operators

Comment: Think of `=` and `+=` as two distinct assignment operators instead of mentally rewriting the second as the first. The `+` operator from variant 1 promotes the arguments to `int` producing an `int` which might cause the  precision loss when converted back to `byte`.

Comment: Thanks, the JLS explanation was exactly what I was looking for.